# Enumerator for a class composing List

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I have:

```
public class MyList : IEnumerable<MyItem>, IEnumerable
{
   private List<MyItem> list = new List<MyItem>();

   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { ??? } 

   IEnumerator<MyItem> IEnumerable<MyItem>.GetEnumerator() { ??? }
}
```

How do I implement these enumerators using the list enumerators ?

Comment: `return list.GetEnumerator()` ?

Comment: that will not work for the second one

Comment: are you really sure ? why do you think it wont?

Comment: "Cannot return a value from iterators. Use the yield return statement to return a value, or yield break to end the iteration"

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I can't create an example if I can't implement the methods ...

Comment: @kofifus also note that you don't actually need to manually add the non-generic IEnumerable implementation label to your class since it's already implemented through IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: Are you sure you need to create your custom IEnumerable? [Read this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/266673/122683)

Comment: @kofifus example doesn't necessarily need to compile. you can add the code that gives you the error you mentioned. it is very surprising that you have 2800 reputation and still not aware of how to ask a question.

Comment: Selman you have been nothing but helpful .. I got my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't have your generic IEnumerable of MyItem be explicit:

```
public class MyList : IEnumerable<MyItem>, IEnumerable
{
    private List<MyItem> list = new List<MyItem>();

    public IEnumerator<MyItem> GetEnumerator() => list.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: One should create a generic list, like `MyList<T>`

Comment: @VMAtm the public GetEnumerator is generic

Comment: If you're saying the class design could be MyList<T> then I'm inclined to agree.

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about the design